# @mention a user in Ms bot with in MS teams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a bot built using ms bot v3 nodejs sdk. I add this bot in my MS team by using deep link for 1:1 conversation which looks like as follows

[https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users=28:{BotID}](https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users=28:%7BBotID%7D)

I would like to add @mentioning users capability to this bot and I was trying to see if I can get some examples on how to it ?

Not sure if side loading bot as an app will allow it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bots and users can only at-mention members of the same conversation.

- In a channel, you can mention any user in the team
- In a 1:1 chat, you can at-mention the other user
- In a group chat, you can mention any user in the chat

Right now neither bots nor users can at-mention arbitrary users who are not members of the conversation.

Your example above, "Hello @PersonB and @PersonC please take care of this ticket", can work if PersonB and PersonC are part of the team (if this in channel), or the group chat, but not in a 1:1 chat with the bot.

The deeplink in your question creates a 1:1 chat w/ the bot, so no other users could be at-mentioned :(

Comment: Hi Adrian,
thanks for precise answer. It looks at At-mention isn't possible in 1:1 chat. I am assuming you just had a typo for following statement from your answer. 

In a 1:1 chat, you can at-mention the other user.

Comment: @RoyJ No typo: in a 1:1 chat, bots and users can at-mention the other party in the chat. It's often superfluous--after all, it's a 1:1 chat--but it's technically possible.

Comment: if deeplink in your question creates a 1:1 chat then as you had mentioned '1:1 chat w/ the bot, so no other users could be at-mentioned '

your other statement is contradictory.  where you say 'No typo: in a 1:1 chat, bots and users can at-mention the other party in the chat'

anyway, is there any official document to share on how to make it technically possible.

Comment: If User A clicks on the deeplink, the conversation will have 2 members: User A and the Bot. The Bot can send messages that mention User A, and User A can at-mention the Bot. Only those two; no others can be mentioned. That's what I meant by "no other users could be at-mentioned".

Comment: Here's how your bot can mention other users. The technique here works in 1:1 and group chats: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bot-conversations/bots-conv-channel#constructing-mentions   (But I think what you really want is for a user to be able to mention/refer to *other* users in a 1:1 chat with the bot, and that is not possible currently.)

Comment: Yeah I was looking 'for a user to be able to mention/refer to other users in a 1:1 chat with the bot'

Thank you for the confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

Bots in single user conversations do not require an @ mention - the user can just type the command. [Bots in channel conversations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bot-conversations/bots-conv-channel) require the user to @ mention the bot to invoke it in a channel.

In order to access your bot into channel, you need to add teams scope to your bot in [App Manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema#bots). Please use [Teams App Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/get-started-app-studio) to create your app manifest. You need to [Upload an app package to Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/apps/apps-upload) to see your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload your bot as a app, for that you need to create an app manifest in JSON format like this.

```
{
"$schema": "https://statics.teams.microsoft.com/sdk/v1.3.0-beta.2/manifest/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
"manifestVersion": "1.3",
"version": "1.3",
"id": "c9edb618-c5de-4be2-**f4-74c1*******1",
"packageName": "com.example.tcafebot",
"developer": {
    "name": "Harsh Raj",
    "websiteUrl": "https://www.sdharshraj.github.io",
    "privacyUrl": "https://privacy.microsoft.com/en-us/privacystatement",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://www.botframework.com/Content/Microsoft-Bot-Framework-Preview-Online-Services-Agreement.htm"
},
"name": {
    "short": "TCafeBot",
    "full": "Tea and Coffee bot"
},
"description": {
    "short": "TCafeBot - a bot helping you with twiter.",
    "full": "It will help you find a user or tweets from twiter. Also it can read text from image or even it can tell what is there in a photo."
},
"icons": {
    "outline": "bot_blue.png",
    "color": "bot_blue.png"
},
"accentColor": "#0079bf",
"configurableTabs": [{
    "configurationUrl": "https://contoso.com/teamstab/configure",
    "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
    "scopes": [
        "team",
        "groupchat"
    ]
}],
"staticTabs": [{
        "contentUrl": "https://harshcognitivebot.azurewebsites.net/loading",
        "entityId": "1on1test123",
        "name": "Bot Info",
        "scopes": [
            "team",
            "personal"
        ]
    },
    {
        "contentUrl": "https://harshcognitivebot.azurewebsites.net/tab-auth/simple",
        "entityId": "simpleAuth",
        "name": "Simple Auth",
        "scopes": [
            "personal"
        ]
    },
    {
        "contentUrl": "https://harshcognitivebot.azurewebsites.net/tab-auth/silent",
        "entityId": "silentAuth",
        "name": "Silent Auth",
        "scopes": [
            "personal"
        ]
    }
],
"bots": [{
    "botId": "c9edb618-c5de-4be2-**f4-74c1*******1",
    "scopes": [
        "team",
        "personal",
        "groupchat"
    ],
    "commandLists": [{
            "scopes": [
                "team"
            ],
            "commands": [{
                    "title": "hello",
                    "description": "Runs the simplest hello dialog"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "scopes": [
                "personal"
            ],
            "commands": [{
                    "title": "hello",
                    "description": "Runs the simplest hello dialog"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}],
"composeExtensions": [{
    "botId": "c9edb618-c5de-4be2-**f4-74c1*******1",
    "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
    "commands": [{
        "id": "search123",
        "description": "Find a card",
        "title": "Search",
        "initialRun": true,
        "parameters": [{
            "title": "query123",
            "name": "query",
            "description": "Search string"
        }]
    }]
}],
"permissions": [
    "identity",
    "messageTeamMembers"
],
"validDomains": [
    "787c30bb.ngrok.io"
]
```

}

And also keep a icon with the name given in the Manifest file.

Then you need to make a zip file of these two files(Manifest and Icon). Note that these two file should not be in any folder you should make a zip directly with the two files.

Then Go to Team App and select upload a custom app there you can browse your zip file.

Also for fetching team details you can refer this [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-context)

Answer (score 0):

To use @mention, add your bot to a Teams channel:

Use Teams App Studio to create an App Manifest zip file. Details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/get-started-app-studio).

Upload the App Manifest zip file to the Teams channel. Go to the Teams channel -> Manage Team -> Apps -> Upload a Custom App link (at the bottom)

Your bot is now available in the channel, and users can talk to it using @mention.

Important tip for bots in Teams - Remove the @mention once the text is received by the Bot (in MessageController.cs), before it is sent to LUIS etc

```
            if (activity.ChannelId == ChannelIds.Msteams)
            {
                //remove bot @mention
                if (activity.Text.Contains("<at>"))
                {
                    activity.Text = Regex.Replace(activity.Text, "<at>.*</at>", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Trim();
                }
            }
```

Comment: I think there is confusion here about what I'm trying to achieve VS what's suggested here.
I am trying to do ATmentioning users capability and NOT ATmentioning the BOT in teams channel.

Comment: Do you mean the bot needs to @mention other users in the channel? Can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: Yes. Here is what I mean,

Person A is talking to bot in 1:1 chat (not in channel) Or could be in teams channel 
 it doesn't matter.

person A says ''Hello @ person B and @person C please take care of this ticket "

Bot takes this request , fetches names from utterance, so in this case  person B's full name and person C full name. and proceeds with business logic. 

Note:- Bot should have capability to fetch any users from o365 tenant. so user could @ mention them. Ms teams already know about all users from the tenant.

Comment: Not sure how a Bot does @mention users, I would edit your question to be more specific on what you need

Comment: I think you got me wrong here. Bot will never @mention a user , instead
A user using a bot in Ms teams will @ mention another user 

make sense ? Sorry if I'm still unclear.